# How to solve this Semantic Errors?

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, gcc, compiler-construction

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void my_handler ( timer_t timerid)
{
    printf("\nHello World\n");
}

int main()
{

 // declare some variables

 timer_t timerid;
 struct itimerspec itime;
 struct sigevent sevp;

 // initalize the sigevent variable
 // the memset is necessary to avoid segmentation faults 
 memset (&sevp, 0, sizeof (struct sigevent));
  sevp.sigev_notify=SIGEV_THREAD;
  sevp.sigev_notify_function=(void *)my_handler;


  timer_create (CLOCK_REALTIME, &sevp, &timerid);
  // initialize the timer specification
 // currently the offset and the period is 5 seconds  // you have to adjust this to your actual needs
  itime.it_value.tv_sec = 5;
  itime.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
  itime.it_interval.tv_sec = 5;
  itime.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

 // create the timer
 timer_settime (timerid, 0, &itime, NULL);

 // this loop has to be adapted, so that the program ends after some time  while(1){
 // sleep(100);

}
```

ERRORS :

```
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/new.d" -MT"src/new.d" -o "src/new.o"  In 'CLOCK_REALTIME' undeclared (first use in this function)  
Field 'tv_nsec' could not be resolved       Semantic Error
Field 'tv_nsec' could not be resolved       Semantic Error
Field 'tv_sec' could not be resolved        Semantic Error
Field 'tv_sec' could not be resolved        Semantic Error
storage size of 'itime' isn't known     C/C++ Problem
```

I am using Linux operating system with Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Did you read [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html)? You're missing a header file specifically mentioned in the manual page.

Comment: someone answered as: succesfully run with -std=gnu99 ?? where to had that ??

Comment: Add it as one of argument in `gcc`.

Answer (score 2):

Add `#include <time.h>` in the beginning.

Comment: I did as you said but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You need two small things.

1. As mentioned above, `#include <time.h>`
2. `timer_create` requires a [feature_test_macro](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)

Regarding (2), when you look at the man page for `time_create`, in the SYNOPSIS area it will tell you what functions require particular macro(s).

So the quick solution is to define the following *as the first line* in the above code and then add the `time.h` header somewhere after that.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
```

The lengthier solution is to read the `feature_test_macro` man page because you will run into this kind of thing all the time.

BTW, make sure you link againt `librt`  i.e. `-lrt`

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. How and where to link -lrt ??

Comment: I don't know how Eclipse handles it but you need to add librt to your link libraries.  I am sure there is a menu item somewhere to do this.  The final result will be your compile command will look something like `gcc -g -Wall -ofoo foo.c -lrt`, etc.